# Fill ArrayList with objects fills with same values

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to fill my empty `ArrayList` "circles" with  objects `Circle` with random sizes and random locations, which I will later on paint. `for` loop fills array normally, but for some reason when I copy it with `circ.addAll(circles)` it doesn't work. I also tried to use `.clone()`, `circ = circles`,... but it ended up with either nullpoint exception error or all circles having same values. This is my code.

```
public class board {
public static int size = 400;
public static ArrayList<Circle> circles;

public static void fillArray(ArrayList<Circle> circ){
    Random r = new Random();
    int rand = r.nextInt(10)+5;
    circles = new ArrayList<Circle>(rand);
    System.out.println("random ="+ rand);
    for(int i = 0; i< rand; i++){


        circles.add(new Circle(Circle.x, Circle.y,Circle.size));

        System.out.println(i+". "+ circles.get(i).x +" "+ circles.get(i).y +" size je "+ circles.get(i).size);
        //fills normaly
    }
        circ.addAll(circles);
        System.out.println("aaaaa"+circ.get(0).x);
        //why same values? 
    System.out.println("fillArray circles= " +circ.get(0).x+circ.get(0).y+ " "+circ.get(1).x);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    fillArray(circles);
}
```

my Circle class looks like this:

```
public class Circle {
public static int x,y;
public static int size;

public Circle(int x, int y, int size) {
    this.x = randomLoc();
    this.y = randomLoc();
    this.size = randomSize();
}
public static int randomSize (){
    int min = 15;
    int max = 30;
    Random r = new Random();
    int rand = r.nextInt(max)+min;
    return rand;

}
public static int randomLoc(){
    int min = 12;
    int max = board.size;
    Random r = new Random();
    int rand = r.nextInt(max)+min;
    return rand;

}}
```

Comment: what exactly is `circ`? and where do you copy it?

Comment: You are not generating random circles. The only random number here is the length of the array. You use for every circle the same values...

Comment: Can you explain what _it doesn't work_  exactly means? You seem to be referring to the same `ArrayList` with both `circ` and `circles` ... pretty sure that's not what you want to do

Comment: `new Circle(Circle.x, Circle.y,Circle.size)` - you are (apparently?) passing the same values to every constructor, so why would you expect the objects to have different values?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer `circ` is the argument for `fillArray` method.

Comment: What are `int k, p` and `size`  for?

Comment: Please show "full code", you have some missing vars and you seem to init all `Circle` instances with the same values (`x,y,size`)... moreover as far as you are using `Circle` attributes to init `Circle` himself, it may be useful to see `Circle` class implementation

Comment: @user1803551 k,p are irrelevant in this stage of program.

Comment: Then remove them. Also, format your code properly while at it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to fill my empty `ArrayList` "circles" with objects `Circle` with random sizes and random locations

But you're not doing that. The line

```
circles.add(new Circle(Circle.x, Circle.y,Circle.size));
```

adds a `Circle` with `static` field values. Presumably, your `Circle` class has something like this:

```
public class Circle {

    public static int x, y, size; // perhaps with some initialized values

    public Circle(int x, int y, int size) { /* ... */ }
}
```

So you add the same values to all the circles in the list. To randomize the size and location you would need to use the `Random` instance you created. Something like:

```
circles.add(new Circle(r.nextInt(10)+5, r.nextInt(10)+5, r.nextInt(10)+5));
```

> For loop fills array normally, but for some reason when I copy it with circ.addAll(circles) it doesn't work.

You are confusing the 2 lists you created - `circ` and `circles`. You are passing the reference `ArrayList<Circle> circles` to the method, which is named `circ` inside the method scope. This is redundant since you can access the `static circles` from within the method without passing it as an argument. I suggest you solve your design issues before anything else.

What you probably want to do it initialize `circ`:

```
circ = new ArrayList<Circle>();
```

and note that the argument passed to the constructor is the initial capacity, which is a performance parameter, and almost certainly shouldn't be random.

Once you do that, the line `circ.addAll(circles);` is meaningless and should be removed. Just print `circ` to see the values (`@Override` `Circle`'s `toString`).

**Note:** It's recommended to use the interface and not the implementation to hold the reference: `List<Circle> list = new ArrayList<>();`. You shouldn't care about the implementation details when all you do are list operations.

Comment: object Circle itself makes circles with randomized values. therefore my forloop fills them perfectly.. I checked with syso and got something like this:
random =11
0. 60 146 size = 36
1. 91 325 size = 15
2. 17 386 size = 28
3. 132 274 size = 30... etc. which is perfect. i'm not sure if i understood correctly. I tried to remove parameter and call function that takes global static array and fill it..  Result stays the same.

Comment: "*object Circle itself makes circles with randomized values.*" And how are we supposed to know that?

Answer (score 0):

`circ.addAll(circles)` may not be working properly because it is only making a shallow copy and adding it to the arraylist. A shallow copy is a only a copy of the pointers of the original data, not the data itself. There may be errors happening behind the scenes because of this. Try adding the circle objects by creating a deep copy with the actual data.